# How to centralise bars in a d3 bar chart?

Tags: angular, css, d3.js, svg

I'm using D3 bar chart in my sample Angular project. My requirement is to centralise all bars in the bar chart, which is left aligned by default. I just saw the CSS property `transform` which when applied to  `<g>` inside `<svg>` will shift the bars as a whole to almost centre, but not the exact centre. Following is the code for the chart.

```
<svg width="800" height="400">
     <g transform="translate()40,20">
            <g class="x-axis">.....</g>
            <g class="y-axis">.....</g>
            <rect x="30" width="30" height="80" />
            <rect x="60" width="10" height="25" />
            <rect x="90" width="15" height="40" />
            <rect x="120" width="20" height="50" />
     </g>
</svg>
```

Also, I need it to be centralised in any screen resolution. Please help me find a solution for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center content of SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45590131/center-content-of-svg)

Comment: No, this link doesn't have fix for my issue.Evenif I use transform with scale property, the bars are not in-tact to center in different resolutions.